# I am getting below exception at “DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());” this statement. “javax.net.ssl.SSLException

Tags: java, rest, api, ssl, testing

I am getting below exception at 
`DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());`

This statement:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Below is the code:

```
HttpURLConnection con; 
String inputLine; 
StringBuffer response=null;

try { 
  URL obj = new URL(null, url, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler()); 
  con = (HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection(); //(HttpsURLConnection)
  con.setRequestMethod(“POST”);
  con.addRequestProperty(“Content-Type”,”application/json”);

  for(Map.Entry prop : header.entrySet()) {
    con.setRequestProperty(prop.getKey(),prop.getValue());
  }

  con.setDoOutput(true); 
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
  wr.writeBytes(postParameters); 
  wr.flush(); 
  wr.close();
} catch (Exception e) {} finally {}
```

Comment: Sounds like the url does not lead to a valid HTTPS connection. I suggest you validate it first via https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to find out if everything is configured correctly.

Comment: Does `url` start with "https:"?

Comment: Thanks! Issue resolved by changing HTTPS to HTTP in below code:
URL obj = new URL(null, url, new sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler());